# How to convert HTML with mathjax to markdown

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I recently working on writing machine learning documentations, the math formulas part usually takes me a lot of time. Sometime I found some markdown generate blogs have similar math formulas I need written using mathjax. If I can convert these html blogs including the mathjax formulas back to markdown, it will save me a lot of time, but I am not sure how to do it. I see people talking about using pandoc. I tried it and it is not working on the formulas. Not sure it is because I used it wrong or my input is in unsupported format.

Command I tried

`pandoc ~/Desktop/test.html -t markdown -o  ~/Desktop/test.md`

Example of my input
[image]

Comment: Pandoc supports a [lot of different ways](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html) to render math. The answer will depend in large part on how the math is being rendered in the existing HTML. The screenshots are not particularly helpful in that regard. You need to provide the HTML source as text (in a code block). Perhaps use your browser's "view source" function to copy and past the HTML. Or, at the very least, point us to a page.

Comment: As an example, your screenshots of your browser's "inspect" tool show the rendered HTML after Javascript has run. It is not clear if the HTML in those screenshots was built by a script or existed in the HTML source. As any HTML to Markdown tool would not run any scripts, the document you see in your browser could be quite different than the one Pandoc sees. In other words, your screenshots are not helpful. We need to see the raw HTML of the document. And text that we can copy and paste is much for useful that an image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion updated screenshot. Here is there the url of an example source https://www.zybuluo.com/yxd/note/611571

Comment: Please copy the text and paste it into your question. Screenshots are useless.

Comment: use both `-s` and `--mathjax` flags...